# convert calendar time to EDM from java

Tags: java, date, calendar, date-format, simpledateformat

Im getting value from type java calendar and I need to change it to EDM format type
which is like

**'2000-12-12T12:00'**

i.e. formattedDateAndTime need to be = **'2000-12-12T12:00'**

when i use the following code i get dump in the last statement

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a
>   Date

```
Calendar fval;
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat tf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDateAndTime = df.format(fval) + "T" + tf.format(fval);
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only format with a `Date` object. Try :

```
Calendar fval = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat tf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDateAndTime = df.format(fval.getTime()) + "T" + tf.format(fval.getTime());
System.out.println(formattedDateAndTime);
```

Output :

```
2013-07-08T09:51:06
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 1):

My Solution to initialize fval:

```
Date fval = new Date(new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis());
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat tf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDateAndTime1 = df.format(fval) + "T" + tf.format(fval);
System.out.println(formattedDateAndTime1);
```

`String.format()` is another way to format objects (see [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)):

```
String formattedDateAndTime2 = String.format("%1$tFT%1$tT",fval);
System.out.println(formattedDateAndTime2);
```